# Circular Buffer C++ Implementation

Tags: c++, circular-list

I was asked this question in an interview, and didn't go through. I know, it needs some improvements, but probably I am missing something big? I would highly appreciate if someone can review it for me, so that I can get to know what I need to work on.

The problem is to complete this skeleton class to implement a circular buffer. I could have done the C++ and header in a different source, but they insisted on doing it all here, assuming it is not part of a big project.

```
class CircularBuffer {
public:
    CircularBuffer(int size)
        : data_(size, 0)
        , next_(0)
        , head_(-1)
    {
    }

    ~CircularBuffer()
    {
    }

    bool empty() 
    {
        return size() == 0;
    }

    int size()
    {
        // TODO: check if head is valid.
        // TODO: check emptiness properly.
        int sz = 0;
        if (head_ >= 0)
        {
            if (next_ > head_)
                sz = next_ - head_;
            else
                sz = next_ + (data_.size() - head_);
        }
        return sz;
    }

    void push(char val) 
    {
        // TODO: check if circularbuffer is full.
        if( size() == data_.size())
        {
            std::cout<<"Buffer is full, can't push anything"<< std::endl;
            return;
        }
        data_[next_++] = val;
        if(head_ < 0)
            head_ = 0;
        if (next_ == data_.size()) 
            next_ = 0;

        displayBuffer(); 
    }

    char pop()
    {
        // TODO: check if head_ is valid.
        if (head_ < 0)
        {
            std::cout<<"Empty Buffer, nothing to pop" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }

        // TODO: adjust head_ after pop.
        char popVal = data_[head_];
        data_[head_++] = 0; // Clean the popped memory- display   purpose

        //Wrap around head_ move
        if (head_ == data_.size())
            head_ = 0;

        // Check if the buffer is empty now?
        if (head_ == next_)
        {
            head_ = -1; //Buffer is empty now
            next_ = 0;
        }

        return popVal;
    }

    void displayBuffer()
    {
        std::cout << std::endl;
        for (auto c: data_)
        {
            std::cout << c << ' ';
        }    
        std::cout << "  |   HEAD = " << head_ << "  NEXT = " << next_ << std::endl;     
    }
private:
    std::vector<char> data_;
    int next_;
    int head_;
};
```

Answer (score 7):

## `#include`

The code was in error until I prefixed it with

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
```

## `~CircularBuffer()`

There's no need to define a destructor that does nothing - just let the compiler generate a default one.

If you wanted this to be a base class, you would provide a virtual destructor, but you can explicitly default it:

```
virtual ~CircularBuffer() = default;
```

I'd say that you are right to omit copy constructor and assignment operator, as the compiler-provided ones will work correctly.

## `empty()`

The reason containers have `empty()` is so that it can be quicker than testing size is non-zero.  So implementing `empty()` in terms of `size()` should be a last resort.  In this case, we set `head` negative to indicate an empty buffer, so we can just test that:

```
bool empty() const
{
    return head < 0;
}
```

Note that I've made this a const method, as we may want to call it on a buffer we don't intend to modify.

## `size()`

There's no need for the `sz` variable, as we set it only to return immediately:

```
size_t size() const
{
    if (head < 0)
        return 0;
    if (next > head)
        return next - head;
    return next + (data.size() - head);
}
```

I've made this const, too, and changed the return type to be more in line with what users will expect.  If I were to be really pedantic, I'd consider `std::vector<char>::size_type`, and adjust the `head` and `next` members accordingly.

You could write a single `return` with a tertiary expression here, but I think the `if` ladder is slightly clearer - that's obviously a judgement call.

## `push()`

As in `empty()`, it's inefficient to call `size()` when we just want to know whether the container is full.  Instead, we can just test `next == head`.  If you *must* produce output, send it to `std::cerr`, not `std::cout`!  Generally, in a library, it's better to report the error to the caller (by exceptions, or perhaps as a return value) rather than to output diagnostics ourselves, but I'll let that stand for now.

It wasn't obvious at first reading that if `head` was negative, then we could depend on `next` being zero.  I would probably not made that assumption, and written something like:

```
    data[next] = val;
    if (head < 0)
        head = next;
    if (++next == data.size())
        next = 0;
```

## `pop()`

Most of the critique of `push()` applies here, so I won't repeat it.  It's not clear why `-1` is chosen as the value to return on failure - was this specified in the requirements?

## `main()`

You provide no `main()` function, which is a shame - it would have been nice to use your unit tests when refactoring.

---

## Modified version

I changed the index types to `size_t`, and defined a constant to indicate empty (as `size_t` doesn't have negative values).

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

class CircularBuffer
{
    static const size_t EMPTY = ~0u;

    std::vector<char> data;
    size_t next = 0;               // index at which next insert will occur
    size_t head = EMPTY;           // index of next pop, or EMPTY marker

public:
    CircularBuffer(size_t size)
        : data(size)
    {
    }

    virtual ~CircularBuffer() = default;

    bool empty() const
    {
        return head == EMPTY;
    }

    size_t size() const
    {
        if (empty())
            return 0;
        if (next > head)
            return next - head;
        return data.size() - head + next;
    }

    void push(char val)
    {
        if (next == head)
            throw std::logic_error("Buffer overrun");

        data[next] = val;
        if (empty())
            head = next;
        if (++next == data.size())
            next = 0;
    }

    char pop()
    {
        if (empty())
            throw std::logic_error("Buffer underrun");

        const char popVal = data[head];

        if (++head == data.size())
            head = 0;

        if (head == next)
            head = EMPTY;

        return popVal;
    }
};
```

---

## Future directions

If you want to set yourself some more challenges, I'd recommend looking at the standard containers (especially `std::queue`) and seeing how you can make the interface look more like theirs.  Implement `front()` and `back()` (easy!), `emplace()`, and some iterators.

Also, you might want to make this a template class, so it can hold any kind of element, not just `char`.

Answer (score 4):

- Both methods modify both `head` and `next`, and the class invariant is quite hard to follow. As an interviewer I'd at least expect an assertion

  ```
      if (head < 0) {
          assert(next == 0);
          head = 0;
      }
  ```

  Better yet, the class should maintain an explicit `size` member. A price for increment/decrement per operation is less than the price of `if`, and the code would be much cleaner.
- `void push()/char pop()` do not inform the caller whether the action was successful or not. Printing an error message doesn't help a client to recover. As an interviewer I'd expect `bool push()` and `std::pair<bool, char> pop()`.
- In any case, the error message should go to `std::cerr`
- The C++ containers uniformly discriminate between `pop()` which *only* pops (and returns nothing), and `top()/front()` which returns the value but does not modify the container. As an interviewer I'd expect adherence to this model.
- I don't know what were the requirements for `displayBuffer()`. As implemented, it *may* be used as a debugging aid, but nothing more.
- `push()` shall not call `displayBuffer()`.